# serial port speed

Tags: serial-port, ppp

I try to connect a device to my windows CE device, through the serial port using ppp and I discovered that the other device (arm-linux) changes its port speed continuously.

It should be 38400 baud but it's not constant.

The speed should be constant?

What I'm doing to chek it is

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS3
```

and the output

```
speed 9600 baud;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
-echo
```

[some time later]

```
speed 38400 baud;
```

[some time later]

```
speed 0 baud;
```

In the windows CE device I get:

```
Error: 679 (Incorrect connection profile)
```

The point is that the speed should be constant in my linux device? or should I check other thinks.

Comment: Add 38400 to the stty command line.

Comment: The Rx and Tx baud rate of the serial port is set locally.  The remote end cannot reconfigure the local settings.  If the Rx baud rate does not match the rate used by the far end, then the received data be be garbage and/or Rx status should indicate framing and/or parity errors.